# How to connect with static ip in virtual box redhat linux

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

Trying to set up static -ip in my RHEL-7.6 virtual box session, instead of DHCP.

i have set up ifcfg-en* & /etc/hosts like the images shown, still when i issue  it throws host not found.

Any suggest would be great help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYTfi.png)

Comment: Is your virtualbox network adapter set to NAT or bridged? If it's NAT I doubt 192.168.122.0 is a valid network unless you specifically went into virtualbox's network settings and changed the NAT settings to 192.168.122.0 for its network. And if it's bridged instead, I doubt if it's a valid network either unless your router's address really is 192.168.122.1, which it probably isn't. But correct me if I'm wrong on either count.

Comment: thanks for replying, am using bridge adaptor & eventually you are right as my router address is as per win10- Wireless LAN Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS . :
   IPv6 Address  : fe80::5128:58c5:4181:8ff0%21
   IPv4 Address.  : 192.168.0.51
   Subnet Mask . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway  : 192.168.0.1    ,Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only n/w:

   Connection-specific DNS . :
    IPv6 Address : fe80::8c0b:5cf1:627e:4862%8
   IPv4 Address.. : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . .. : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . :  , so do i need to change to 192.168.0.1 ?